# Grafana getting extra \\ before . operator which is there in my variable name

Tags: grafana

I am new to Grafana and using the Grafana variable and variable value which is passed dynamically is something like this -

`sample.demo`

But when I access this in the panel with $ then the variable value passed to query as -

`sample\\.demo`

Can someone help me what changes do I need to do to my configuration where i am getting variable value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `${var_name:raw}` to tell grafana not to escape the variable value.

> Turns off data source-specific formatting, such as single quotes in an
> SQL query.
>
> servers = ['test1.', 'test2']
> String to interpolate: '${var_name:raw}'
> Interpolation result: '{test.1,test2}'

Please see documentation [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/advanced-variable-format-options/#raw)